# flashlight that flash as per beat of the music

Tags: iphone, flash

how can i develop or is there any way to achieve the flashlight flash on the beat of the music?

i have search over google for the functionality but won't found anything that will draw me the exact way so i would like to have some expert advice that if anyone had done that before or have an idea how to do it?

looking for something like [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t9ZLbJQDWIk)

i know how to turn on and off the flash light here is the code but don't know how to handle that on beat of music

```
-(void) turnTorchOn: (bool) on 
{
    Class captureDeviceClass = NSClassFromString(@"AVCaptureDevice");
    if (captureDeviceClass != nil) {
        AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
        if ([device hasTorch] && [device hasFlash]){

            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
            if (on) {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
                torchIsOn = YES;
            } else {
                [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
                torchIsOn = NO;            
            }
            [device unlockForConfiguration];
        }
    }
}
```

please help thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Having no knowledge whatsoever regarding Audio-technology I have stumbled upon a tutorial that should help you out pretty easily. The tutorial is for a music visualizer however the foundation is alike.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/36475/how-to-make-a-music-visualizer-in-ios